# Why my onclick function does not work for scroll to the target element?

Tags: javascript, php, html

href to `?navito=contact` be successful and can add my `contact.php` file, but the `onclick` function can't scroll into portfolio id.

php code :

```
<?php
  $nav = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'navito');
  if (!isset($nav)) {
     $nav = 'home';
  }
?>

<div>
   <a class="page-scroll" href="?navito=contact" onclick ="down()">Contact</a>
</div>

<section id="portfolio" class="bg-light-gray">
    <?php
        switch ($nav) {
            case 'home':
                include_once 'View/home.php';
                break;
            case 'contact':
                include_once 'View/contact.php';
                break;
            default:
                include_once 'View/home.php';
                break;
        }
    ?>
</section>
```

JS Code:

```
function down(){
    var x= document.getElementById("portfolio");
    x.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? Most browsers have developer mode where you can inspect and step through your client code easily.

Comment: The easiest way is to call the id of the div in the a href

Comment: yes , if i only want to scroll to the div , but i want to href that to ?nav= contact and include the contact.php , and i want to scoll that to the div id @KebabProgrammer

Comment: Edit the text of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off just using a `button` than adding an `onclick` attribute to an anchor tag - that can get messy:

```js
function down() {
  document.getElementById("portfolio").scrollIntoView();
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 1000px;
}

button {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="page-scroll" onclick="down()">Contact</button>
</div>

<span id="portfolio" class="bg-light-gray">
  <a href="#">Here we are</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` function is always executed **before** the navigation to the address in `href`. Also, this navigation will cause the page to reload completely. Since the function `down()` already executed in the first step, at the newly reloaded page there will be no sign the function was ever executed.

My suggestion is to set the `down()` function to be executed as soon as the page is loaded.

```
function down() {
    ...
}

window.onload = down;
```

Comment: i really don't undertand , i just want do href="?navito=contact" ,  and auto scroll to id div , do you have other suggestion ,without uses onclick ?

Comment: If I understood your code correctly, you need the page to reload in order to the php code execute again, generating a new page where the section `portfolio`will have the correct content. In fact, with my suggestion, the `onclick` section is no longer required. The `window.onload = down;` will care of the scrolling as soon as the page is reloaded.